# Read parameter from XAML Post build argument into Powershell Script

Tags: xml, git, powershell, xaml, tfs

I have a powershell script which is reading node value according to 'type' from a XML property file,now i want to read one parameter 'type' node value from TFS Git XAML build process.How can declare a parameter in XAML build process and read it at the time of build in to the script?

```
$env="Read from XAML build Process"

$xmlDocPath="D:\*****\ScriptsConfig.xml";
[xml]$xmlFile = Get-Content $xmlDocPath;
$PathToDropUIcssandjss=$xml.Objects.Object | Where-Object {$_.type -eq $env} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PathToDropUIcssandjss
$DeployingPackageBranchFolderName=$xml.Objects.Object | Where-Object {$_.type -eq $args[0]} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DeployingPackageBranchFolderName
$BranchName=$xml.Objects.Object | Where-Object {$_.type -eq $env} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BranchName
$ProjectName=$xml.Objects.Object | Where-Object {$_.type -eq $env} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProjectName
$Automation=$xml.Objects.Object | Where-Object {$_.type -eq $env} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Automation
$DeploymentEnvironment=$xml.Objects.Object | Where-Object {$_.type -eq $env} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DeploymentEnvironment
```

Comment: Did you just mean you want to assign variable in PowerShell script during TFS build process? Are you using InvokeProcess activity?

Comment: I don't have Invoke process in my Git Template

Answer (score 0):

I am able to read the parameter from TFS now by the command below

```
  [CmdletBinding()]
    param([string]$args)

    $env=[string]$args
```

But the parameter $env is not working in the below shown commands but its working outside this block if i am displaying it separately

```
$SourceDir = $Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY
$xmlDocPath="$SourceDir\ScriptsConfig.xml";
[xml]$xmlFile = Get-Content $xmlDocPath;
$PathToDropUIcssandjss=$xml.Objects.Object | Where-Object {$_.type -eq $env} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PathToDropUIcssandjss
$DeployingPackageBranchFolderName=$xml.Objects.Object | Where-Object {$_.type -eq $env} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DeployingPackageBranchFolderName
$BranchName=$xml.Objects.Object | Where-Object {$_.type -eq $env} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BranchName
$ProjectName=$xml.Objects.Object | Where-Object {$_.type -eq $env} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProjectName
$Automation=$xml.Objects.Object | Where-Object {$_.type -eq $env} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Automation
$DeploymentEnvironment=$xml.Objects.Object | Where-Object {$_.type -eq $env} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DeploymentEnvironment
```